# Planning to implement stop and wait algorithm in c

Tags: c, udp, flow-control

The algorithm I considered is as follows.

1) sender sends data using sendto().

2) waits for ACK packet from the receiver.

3-1) sends the same packet if ACK for the next packet hasn't arrived within timeout.

3-2) sends the next one if ACK for the next packet arrived.

Just the same way as a normal algorithm. What I'm wondering is the way to count the timeout and wait for the ACK using recvfrom(). I first thought to use thread but there must be a better approach. How can I handle those two at the same time? Should I use a while statement with time related variable in it?

Comment: On unix-likes, you use [poll](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/poll.html) or [select](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/select.html), both which time out if nothing has been received in a certain time.